# QR codes for hyperrefs

Tags: hyperref, marginpar, qrcode

There are lots of hyperrefs in a document I'm writing (pdflatex workflow, no pstricks please). In the preamble I have

```
\def\Marginpar#1{\marginpar[{\bf \hfill {#1}}]{\bf #1}}

\def\Qref#1#2{\href{#1}{#2}\Marginpar{\qrcode[hyperlink,height=12mm]{#1}}}
```

and for each clickable link in the text I simply put `\Qref{url}{text}`
which generates a nice QR code on the margin. This helps the unlucky reader who uses the dead tree copy, as long as they have a QR scanner app on their phone. The problem is there are too many of these QR codes, and the margin gets crowded. I'd like to alternate placement *within one page* between left and right margins. This presumably takes a binary counter that gets toggled each time `Qref` is called, resetting to the default placement at the top of each page? Ideally, this method would be resorted to only if latex decides the QR boxes are indeed overcrowding the margin space, but that may be too much to ask.